# Drop down javascript not changing sub drop downs

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this javascript here in console to select a dropdown menu value

`(function ($) { $('select[name="groupid"]').val('Crew Group'); }).call(this, jQuery);`

It chooses my selection as i want. But it will not change the sub sections of the dropdown when i use this code. But if i actually do it by clicking it will.

What extra javascript can i ru to make this work?

Heres a screenshot below  basically if i click Crew Group it will change all those sub sections to certain values below. But with the javascript it doesnt.

**Basically if I click Crew Group in the Group* dropdown itll change all those values beneath it. If i use the javascript it doesnt although it will select that choice.**

[image]

Do i need to focus on it or something? Or select it again? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.change()` at the end to trigger the `change` event:

```
$('select[name="groupid"]').val('Crew Group').change();
```

Comment: Just tried it. Didnt work although it does select it then values beneath didnt change.

Comment: Do you have a `.change` event for the above select

Comment: What do you mean? Im fairly noobish at javascript.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript linked to the above select?

Comment: Not at all i dont see any.

Comment: So, when you simply click it and it alters the below selects, where is the code that does the altering?

Comment: `<td width="73%" class="Spc_Tbl"> <select name="groupid" id="groupid" style="width:168px"> <option value="0">Select Here</option><option value="1">Open Group</option><option value="16">Crew Group</option></select></td>`

Comment: Nope not that, thats the HTML -- when you actually click it you say it alters the below selects, how is it altering them

Comment: Let me look closely maybe i can find something. Is there a way to see what code it could be when i click it?

Comment: Probably something like `$("select").change()` or `document.getElementById("id").onchange = function;`

Comment: Let me look for it. Is it possible to find in console what javascript runs when i click on it in chrome?

Comment: Can't see that, proxy :\

Comment: I see this. `handler: function (){d.events[b](d.object,d.key,c)}
isAttribute: false
lineNumber: 1
listenerBody: "function (){d.events[b](d.object,d.key,c)}"
node: select#groupid
sourceName: "https://192.168.100.1/javascript/common_min.js?version=10.04%20build%202527"
type: "change"
useCapture: true`

Comment: Hmm..no...not sure. If there's a JavaScript change handler, the above code will trigger it. Not sure where yours is coming from.

Comment: and above it says select#groupid

Comment: Is there a way to simulare clicking or pressing enter after i select using `(function ($) { $('select[name="groupid"]').val('Crew Group'); }).call(this, jQuery);
`